# Why does a NumberFormatException occur when a StringUUID received from a Header is parsed to a UUID in Java?

Tags: java, string, rest, uuid

**Client**

```
System.out.println(UUID.fromString("7b11af48-d117-4325-b957-75f9ab87ca4d"));
```

works, but when the UUID is received from a header

```
UUID.fromString(response.getHeaders().get("ID").toString());
```

it results in:

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "[7b11af48"
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
    at java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:589)
    at java.lang.Long.valueOf(Long.java:776)
    at java.lang.Long.decode(Long.java:928)
    at java.util.UUID.fromString(UUID.java:198)
```

while the String looks like a valid UUID:

```
System.out.println(response.getHeaders().get("archiveID").toString());
```

results in:

```
[7b11af48-d117-4325-b957-75f9ab87ca4d]
```

**Server**

```
@Override
public void doPost( HttpServletRequest request,
                       HttpServletResponse response ) throws IOException
{
    response.setHeader("ID", "7b11af48-d117-4325-b957-75f9ab87ca4d"); 
}
```

Comment: Delete the `[` and `]` before `UUID.fromString`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`getHeaders().get(...)` returns a list, which when you call `toString()` will display all the contents wrapped in `[` and `]`.

You could use `getHeaders().get("ID").get(0)` if you know that the header will always exist.